# How do you mock the value of *ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-go

I am currently trying to get used to TDD and on a current project I am working on I am trying to leverage AWS's Go SDK. Which is all fine and dandy and I have used it before but I am currently trying to mock the value that `*ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput` sends.

Diving into the code I see this as what returns for `*ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput`:

```golang
type DescribeVolumesOutput struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"`

    // The NextToken value to include in a future DescribeVolumes request. When
    // the results of a DescribeVolumes request exceed MaxResults, this value can
    // be used to retrieve the next page of results. This value is null when there
    // are no more results to return.
    NextToken *string `locationName:"nextToken" type:"string"`

    // Information about the volumes.
    Volumes []*Volume `locationName:"volumeSet" locationNameList:"item" type:"list"`
}
```

Okay.. That's cool, but what I want to mock the output of must live inside of `Volumes []*Volume`locationName:"volumeSet" locationNameList:"item" type:"list"` so let's go a little deeper and see what that is...

```golang
type Volume struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"`

    // Information about the volume attachments.
    Attachments []*VolumeAttachment `locationName:"attachmentSet" locationNameList:"item" type:"list"`

    // The Availability Zone for the volume.
    AvailabilityZone *string `locationName:"availabilityZone" type:"string"`

    // The time stamp when volume creation was initiated.
    CreateTime *time.Time `locationName:"createTime" type:"timestamp"`

    // Indicates whether the volume will be encrypted.
    Encrypted *bool `locationName:"encrypted" type:"boolean"`

    // The number of I/O operations per second (IOPS) that the volume supports.
    // For Provisioned IOPS SSD volumes, this represents the number of IOPS that
    // are provisioned for the volume. For General Purpose SSD volumes, this represents
    // the baseline performance of the volume and the rate at which the volume accumulates
    // I/O credits for bursting. For more information, see Amazon EBS Volume Types
    // (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html)
    // in the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud User Guide.
    //
    // Constraints: Range is 100-16,000 IOPS for gp2 volumes and 100 to 64,000IOPS
    // for io1 volumes, in most Regions. The maximum IOPS for io1 of 64,000 is guaranteed
    // only on Nitro-based instances (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances).
    // Other instance families guarantee performance up to 32,000 IOPS.
    //
    // Condition: This parameter is required for requests to create io1 volumes;
    // it is not used in requests to create gp2, st1, sc1, or standard volumes.
    Iops *int64 `locationName:"iops" type:"integer"`

    // The full ARN of the AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) customer master
    // key (CMK) that was used to protect the volume encryption key for the volume.
    KmsKeyId *string `locationName:"kmsKeyId" type:"string"`

    // The size of the volume, in GiBs.
    Size *int64 `locationName:"size" type:"integer"`

    // The snapshot from which the volume was created, if applicable.
    SnapshotId *string `locationName:"snapshotId" type:"string"`

    // The volume state.
    State *string `locationName:"status" type:"string" enum:"VolumeState"`

    // Any tags assigned to the volume.
    Tags []*Tag `locationName:"tagSet" locationNameList:"item" type:"list"`

    // The ID of the volume.
    VolumeId *string `locationName:"volumeId" type:"string"`

    // The volume type. This can be gp2 for General Purpose SSD, io1 for Provisioned
    // IOPS SSD, st1 for Throughput Optimized HDD, sc1 for Cold HDD, or standard
    // for Magnetic volumes.
    VolumeType *string `locationName:"volumeType" type:"string" enum:"VolumeType"`
}
```

Nice! this looks like some data that I want to mock the values of!

But over the last couple of days I have had no luck in actually mocking these values. Are they so nested that this type of mocking is not worth the effort? Even trying to use the `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2/ec2iface` does not seem to help me wrap my head around how to properly package some mock value returns to test. Am I coming at TDD all wrong? am I missing something super obvious? I do not really have example code to show since I now no longer understand what I am trying to do.

Does anyone possibly have an example of how they have mocked this?

Comment: can you elaborate on the methods you are calling to get this `DescribeVolumesOutput ` The trick should be to mock a service method and expect an already known value.

Comment: @diyoda_ I have yet to make the methods since I am trying TDD, and failing at it, and trying to create the tests first. Basically the method will use `DescribeVolumesOutput` to check each volume for tags and return the VolumeId for each. so what I want to mock are tag values and volume id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to mock the type, you are able to mock only implementation of the interface. In your case I assume that you are trying to call [DescribeVolumes](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/ec2/ec2iface/interface.go#L1032) and in the response get value constructed by you.
To do that you need to create a mock like

```golang
type MockEC2API struct {
    ec2iface.EC2API // embedding of the interface is needed to skip implementation of all methods
    DescribeVolumesMethod func(*ec2.DescribeVolumesInput) (*ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput, error)
}

func (m *MockEC2API) DescribeVolumes(in *ec2.DescribeVolumesInput) (*ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput, error) {
    if m.DescribeVolumesMethod != nil {
        return m.DescribeVolumesMethod(in)
    }
    return nil, nil // return any value you think is good for you
}
```

In the test create instance of `MockEC2API` instead of the real `ec2.EC2` and provide it with function that will be called and return your's prepared `ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput` result

```golang
...
ec2 := &MockEC2API{
    DescribeVolumesMethod: func(*ec2.DescribeVolumesInput) (*ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput, error) {
        return &ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput{...your initialization...}, nil
    }
}
...
output, err := ec2.DescribeVolumes(in) // this output will be your prepared initialization
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you this clarifies a lot! However I am still confused on this part `&ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput{...your initialization...}` if I can not mock the types then how am I supposed to make what the outputs are? I guess I am mostly lost on how to prepare an `ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput` result.

Comment: For instance I want to mock tag and volume id values. How would I initialize those?

Comment: @AlexCosta  
`volumeId := "Your mock for VolumeId"`  
`tagKey := "Your mock for Tag Key"`  
`tagValue := "Your mock for Tag Value"`  
`tag := ec2.Tag{Key: &tagKey, Value: &tagValue}`  
`mocked := &ec2.DescribeVolumesOutput{`  
    `Volumes: []*ec2.Volume{{VolumeId: &volumeId, Tags: []*ec2.Tag{&tag}}}`  
`}`

Comment: AHHHHHH Thank you! This now makes sense to me!

Comment: 2 years later and still as useful as ever. Really good example, take my upvote!